# Can a Vulcan trick another Vulcan into thinking they cured their pon farr?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, pon-farr

From Star Trek ENT: [In a Mirror Darkly](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly_(episode)):

> T'POL: I lured you away from Engineering with the promise of a sexual encounter.
>
> [T'Pol's quarters - memory]
>
> T'POL: My mind to your mind.
>
> T'POL [OC]: Once we were alone in my quarters, I implanted a telepathic suggestion.
>
> T'POL: My thoughts to your thoughts.
>
> T'POL [OC]: I compelled you to sabotage the power grid.
>
> [Engineering]
>
> T'POL: After you completed the assignment, we melded again. I altered your memory of what had happened. It was my duty to help Captain Forrest regain command.

It would seem that Vulcans can to some extent make a human believe whatever they want, and this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51812/144649) seems to suggest they can manipulate human minds.

Can a Vulcan manipulate another Vulcan into thinking whatever they want? Perhaps that they cured their pon farr (before any points out, I'm aware that the Vulcan attempting manipulate the other Vulcan can just mate, but, depending on the situation it might not be ideal) or are their minds more sophisticated?

From DS9: [The Maquis](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/441.htm):

> SAKONNA: This is quite puzzling. I am unable to establish a mind meld. It would appear he has the ability to shield his thoughts.
>
> DUKAT: It's simply a matter of discipline.

My **guess** would be a properly trained Vulcan can resist being tricked.

Comment: If pon farr were mental and not physiological, then surely Vulcans of all people could train it out of themselves

Comment: Interesting. What would happen if you tried to hypnotize a male human into thinking he wasn't horny?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron you can trick his mind, but you cannot trick his... secondary mind :)

Comment: If it's possible to "cure" pon farr like this, I would think they would have the mental discipline to do it themselves without having to be tricked.